# Cauchy Integral Formula who opened?

Tags: mathematics-social-history

Cauchy Integral Formula who actually proved it? The teacher asked the following task: who actually discovered this integral formula? need historical background, but it's not Cauchy! Help!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a homework problem with no effort on OP's part.

Comment: In Reinhold Remmert *Theory of Complex Functions* around p. 145 you can find the information that Poisson had a similar formula years earlier without realizing its power.

Comment: Two references worth getting ahold of to investigate this are [**The Higher Calculus: A History of Real and Complex Analysis from Euler to Weierstrass**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0387963022) by Bottazzini (1986) and [**Hidden Harmony―Geometric Fantasies. The Rise of Complex Function Theory**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/1461457246) by Bottazzini/Gray (2013). If not available at a library near you, maybe interlibrary loan is a possibility.

Comment: By the way, the correct title should be "Who discovered the Cauchy Integral Formula?" The word "to open" in English has a somewhat different use from "открыть" in Russian. For instance, you can use "open" to ask your children, "Who opened the box of candies?"

Comment: Пожалуйста, скажите нам настоящий вопрос: кто открыл эту формулу, кто доказал формулу в практических условиях, или кто доказал формулу в минимальных условиях?  Это отдельные вопросы. Для каких функций инструктор доказал интегральную формулу?

Comment: Пожалуйста, прочитайте комментарии.

Comment: thanks everyone!

Comment: I voted to reopen because, even if it is a homework problem, it stimulated a very scholarly answer from @KCd, which I think is valuable for this site.

Answer (score 5):

You asked two questions: who first *discovered* the formula and who first *proved* it.  Which is the question you are asking here?  Someone might have found the formula with incorrect hypotheses and a mistaken proof before someone else gave a correct statement and proof. Perhaps the first person could be said to have discovered the formula without having proved it.

In addition to the books mentioned in comments above, look also at Jeremy Gray's *The Real and the Complex: A History of Analysis in the 19th Century*.

The original development of complex analysis by Cauchy had incorrect or unclear hypotheses about the type of functions to which the main results (integral representation theorem and residue theorem) could be applied. It wasn’t until the 1850s that Cauchy understood how complex-valued functions of one complex variable were much more special than complex-valued functions of two real variables, especially the significance of complex differentiability. The first textbook on complex analysis, by Briot and Bouquet, came out in 1859. It took many years for different properties of complex functions to be recognized as describing the *same* functions, and that's why many different labels were introduced for what we now call analytic functions: analytic, holomorphic, monodromic, monogenic, regular, and synectic.  Today only two terms survive: analytic and holomorphic.

In Section 3.5.7 of the book by Bottazzini and Gray mentioned in a comment above, they write on p. 151 an equation that is

> the form in which Cauchy first presented his celebrated “integral formula”

but it is an integral over $[-\pi,\pi]$ rather than an integral over a circle (think of a circle parameterized by angles in $[-\pi,\pi]$) since Cauchy did not have the viewpoint of integration in the complex plane.

Later they say (pp. 183-184) that a paper of Cauchy's in 1846

> is commonly — but incorrectly — credited by historians with containing the first general statement of the Cauchy integral theorem.

On p. 185 they say

> contrary to the popular version of this story, there is no reference in [Cauchy's 1846 paper] to either complex functions or complex integration.

The last paragraph of that section says

> the crucial year 1846 showed that Cauchy was well acquainted with the basic facts about complex functions, including the idea of representing complex variables in a plane, the integral theorem—now stated in a more general setting than in his (1825a)— the concept of a residue and the integral formula. Yet a comprehensive theory of complex functions was still lacking. In addition, there were unanswered questions about the nature of branch-points and the multi-valuedness of complex functions and integrals that he was unable to deal with in a satisfactory way.

In Section 3.6.3, they discuss the work of Briot and Bouquet that

> eventually formulated the correct hypothesis one has to require for Cauchy’s theorem, i.e. the existence of a unique derivative $f'(z)$ (independent of the path).

Based on that, I suggest looking up the work of Briot and Bouquet.

The modern version of Cauchy's integral formula assumes $f$ is complex-differentiable but *not* that $f'$ is continuous, and the fact that the formula is valid under such weak conditions is due to Goursat in 1900 (Transactions AMS vol. 1, pp. 14-16 [here](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1900-001-01/S0002-9947-1900-1500519-7/S0002-9947-1900-1500519-7.pdf)). At the start of that paper he writes that the proof he gave in 1884 (Acta Mathematica vol. 4, pp. 197-200) did not need a continuity of  $f'$ but this fact was perhaps not made clear in 1884, and he was writing the paper in 1900 to be more explicit about not needing continuity of $f'$.  So perhaps the answer is Goursat, although it seems strange to say the Cauchy integral formula was first *discovered* in 1900.

Section 8.5.4 of the Bottazzini/Gray book gives more details about what Goursat did and they particularly emphasize the related work of Pringsheim.

Comment: I do recall, admittedly decades ago, still seeing "regular" in (relatively old) English-language texts on complex function theory, and hearing some older complex analysts use that language. :)

Comment: I guess one could also mention Goursat, who "correctly" minimized the hypotheses...

Comment: @paulgarrett  I added a paragraph about Goursat at the end.